# Jquery auto complete text box ajax call issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building an autocomplete text field with jquery and ajax like the google search bar. The ajax call is supposed to be fired on keyup but it is not working. Note that when I input a variable manually in my php file it is working properly. So the problem must come from my ajax "call" but I can't figure it out. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

My HTML:

```
<input id="recherche" type='text' placeholder="je recherche">
<div id="resultat"></div>
```

My JS:

```
$('#recherche').keyup(function() {
    var recherche = $(this).val();
    var ajaxData = "recherche=" + recherche;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/reherche.php",
        data: ajaxData,
        success: function(retour) { // si l'appel a bien fonctionné
            $('#resultat').html(retour);

        }
    });

});
```

My CSS:

```
#resultat{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid blue;}
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("connect.inc.php");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$recherche = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['recherche']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT LOC_VKUP FROM T_LOC WHERE LOC_VKUP LIKE '%$recherche%'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<div id="result">'.$row['LOC_VKUP'].'</div>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console? What is your PHP script returning?

Comment: I am new to developping, so how can I debugg with console. I am using textWrangler. Buy the way when I input the var $recherche manually in my php file the query is executed properly.

Comment: Google chrome has a built-in debugger you can access by pressing F12. Firefox needs the firebug add-on which is also opened with F12. As for using these debugging tools, well I'm afraid that's beyond the scope of this comment box so maybe post a live example or the output of your PHP script.

Comment: The console says 404. File not found. The php file is is my php folder. The js file in my js folder. and the index.php at the root.

Comment: I don't get it. I tried all paths. Still not working. It is strange.

Comment: In some places you have 'recherche' while in the URL for your AJAX call you have 'reherche'.  Is that missing a 'c'?

Comment: Helo rrr. You are right. Thank you very much. That was it. Make an "official" answer so I can accept if if you like.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to accomplish, I would consider using the jQuery autocomplete function rather than keyup.  More information can be found here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ .  This is built directly into jQuery and no plugins are needed.

Hope this helps!